# Trying to use python API to output depth and normal images -- but no files are outputted

Tags: python, depth-map

I've copied my script below. The script runs fine and it feels like everything is set up correctly but no depth or normal files are outputted ... is my renderer maybe not using the right output node?

Any guidance very much appreciated!

````
import os, math
import bpy

# Set up rendering
context = bpy.context
scene = bpy.context.scene
render = bpy.context.scene.render

render.engine = "BLENDER_EEVEE"
render.image_settings.color_mode = "RGB"  # ('RGB', 'RGBA', ...)
render.image_settings.color_depth = "8"
render.image_settings.file_format = "PNG"
render.resolution_x = 256
render.resolution_y = 256
render.resolution_percentage = 100
render.film_transparent = True

scene.use_nodes = True

nodes = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes
links = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.links

# Clear default nodes
for n in nodes:
    nodes.remove(n)

# Create input render layer node
render_layers = nodes.new("CompositorNodeRLayers")

# Create depth output nodes
depth_file_output = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
depth_file_output.label = "Depth Output"
depth_file_output.base_path = ""
depth_file_output.file_slots[0].use_node_format = True
depth_file_output.format.file_format = "OPEN_EXR"
depth_file_output.format.color_depth = "16"
links.new(render_layers.outputs["Depth"], depth_file_output.inputs[0])


# Create normal output nodes
scale_node = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeMixRGB")
scale_node.blend_type = "MULTIPLY"
# scale_node.use_alpha = True
scale_node.inputs[2].default_value = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
links.new(render_layers.outputs["Normal"], scale_node.inputs[1])

bias_node = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeMixRGB")
bias_node.blend_type = "ADD"
# bias_node.use_alpha = True
bias_node.inputs[2].default_value = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0)
links.new(scale_node.outputs[0], bias_node.inputs[1])

normal_file_output = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
normal_file_output.label = "Normal Output"
normal_file_output.base_path = ""
normal_file_output.file_slots[0].use_node_format = True
normal_file_output.format.file_format = "PNG"
links.new(bias_node.outputs[0], normal_file_output.inputs[0])

# Create albedo output nodes
alpha_albedo = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeSetAlpha")
links.new(render_layers.outputs["DiffCol"], alpha_albedo.inputs["Image"])
links.new(render_layers.outputs["Alpha"], alpha_albedo.inputs["Alpha"])

albedo_file_output = nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeOutputFile")
albedo_file_output.label = "Albedo Output"
albedo_file_output.base_path = ""
albedo_file_output.file_slots[0].use_node_format = True
albedo_file_output.format.file_format = "PNG"
albedo_file_output.format.color_mode = "RGB"
albedo_file_output.format.color_depth = "8"
links.new(alpha_albedo.outputs["Image"], albedo_file_output.inputs[0])


# Delete default cube
context.active_object.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.delete()


bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")

################ START SCENE LOGIC #################
# Add cube to scene
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
cube.location = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

################ END SCENE LOGIC ###################

obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

# Possibly disable specular shading
for slot in obj.material_slots:
    node = slot.material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
    node.inputs["Specular"].default_value = 0.05


# Make light just directional, disable shadows.
light = bpy.data.lights["Light"]
light.type = "SUN"
light.use_shadow = False
# Possibly disable specular shading:
light.specular_factor = 1.0
light.energy = 10.0

# Add another light source so stuff facing away from light is not completely dark
bpy.ops.object.light_add(type="SUN")
light2 = bpy.data.lights["Sun"]
light2.use_shadow = False
light2.specular_factor = 1.0
light2.energy = 0.015
bpy.data.objects["Sun"].rotation_euler = bpy.data.objects["Light"].rotation_euler
bpy.data.objects["Sun"].rotation_euler[0] += 180

# Place camera
cam = scene.objects["Camera"]
cam.location = (0, 10, 5)
cam.data.lens = 35
cam.data.sensor_width = 32

cam_constraint = cam.constraints.new(type="TRACK_TO")
cam_constraint.track_axis = "TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z"
cam_constraint.up_axis = "UP_Y"

cam_empty = bpy.data.objects.new("Empty", None)
cam_empty.location = (0, 0, 0)
cam.parent = cam_empty

scene.collection.objects.link(cam_empty)
context.view_layer.objects.active = cam_empty
cam_constraint.target = cam_empty

view_count = 10
stepsize = 360.0 / view_count
rotation_mode = "XYZ"

model_identifier = "cube"
fp = os.path.join(os.path.abspath("../data"), model_identifier, model_identifier)

for i in range(0, view_count):
    print("Rotation {}, {}".format((stepsize * i), math.radians(stepsize * i)))

    render_file_path = fp + "_r_{0:03d}".format(int(i * stepsize))

    scene.render.filepath = render_file_path
    depth_file_output.file_slots[0].path = render_file_path + "_depth"
    normal_file_output.file_slots[0].path = render_file_path + "_normal"
    albedo_file_output.file_slots[0].path = render_file_path + "_albedo"

    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)  # render still

    cam_empty.rotation_euler[2] += math.radians(stepsize)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your generated compositor setup, after moving nodes around, you'll see this:

[image]

The normal and depth output nodes are not connected to the `Render Layers` output. Add these two lines in your script after `scene.use_nodes = True`

```
scene.view_layers["ViewLayer"].use_pass_normal = True
scene.view_layers["ViewLayer"].use_pass_z = True
```

This is the script version of adding these layer outputs when selecting *View Layer Properties > Passes > Data > Z/Normal*.
The compositor setup should now look similar to this and output the files:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed